# Number of equivalence classes A = $\{100000,...,999999\}$

Tags: combinatorics, quotient-set

I am asked to find the number of elements in the quotient set of $A\times A \quad$ $A=\{100000,...,999999\}$ considering that the defined relationship n~m $\Leftrightarrow$ n and m they have exactly the same digits except for the order in which they appear, for example 347222~272432 and 110001~100011.

What is the correct way to do this exercise? I have tried several ways without success.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: In the English-speaking world, $999.999$ means $999+\frac{999}{1000}$. I suspect you mean $999999$.

Comment: Rephrase the question... "How many 6 digit numbers with non-strictly decreasing numbers are there?"  To answer this, stars-and-bars is ideal, and take note that $000000$ is not a six-digit number

Comment: @JMoravitz: Not strictly decreasing digits, but rather non-increasing digits. (At least to me *strictly decreasing* excludes repeated digits.)

Comment: Right, I misspoke, a bit distracted., but the suggestion still stands, and the ability to recognize that this is a stars-and-bars problem in disguise is arguably the most important step